# Showing that every model is infinite

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Given the theory (set of FOL formulas)

$$ T = \{\forall x_1 \neg Q(x_1,x_1), \forall x_1 \exists x_2 Q(x_1,x_2), \forall x_1 \forall x_2 \forall x_3 (Q(x_1,x_2) \land Q(x_2,x_3)) \to Q(x_1,x_3)\} $$

Show that every model for $T$ is infinite.

I tried to assume that there exists a finite model, but I could not see the contradiction. Any suggestion?

Comment: so your model is wrong. Because Q(1,2) and Q(2,1) needs to imply Q(1,1) which is impossible. What went wrong here might tell you why finiteness will not be possible.

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I fixed it Thanks.

Comment: still doesnt work, the second part of $T$ is violated as there is nothing that satisfies $Q(3,-)$

Comment: Yes, I could see that it does have to be infinite. I am just not sure how to precisely define a model in this case and prove rigorously that it has to be infinite. For the latter, would a contradiction proof work?

Comment: Yes a contradiction should work. Show for example that in a finite model, the last two conditions will always lead to some $Q(x,x)$ which is not allowed.

Comment: Hint for part $1$: what choice of $Q$ makes $x_n=n$ work? Hint for part $2$: given a sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ with $Q(x_n,\,x_{n+1})$, prove $Q(x_i,\,x_j)$ is never true with $i\ge j$. Hence prove the sequence never repeats.

Comment: @J.G. I thought about the hint for part 2 but I couldn't really follow it. I'd be grateful if you can elaborate more. We want to prove that every model is infinite. Okay, we can think about this sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1})$ that constitutes the domain. 1) why can't you for example take $Q(x_{n+1},x_n)$? 2) I see why $\neq Q(x_i,x_j)$  for $i=j$ by the theory $T$, but why it should hold for $i>j$? 3) I still don't see how "prove the sequence never repeats" is deduced and how it is going to help.

Comment: Using transitivity repeatedly viz. induction on $i-j$, $Q(x_j,\,x_i)$. The sequence doesn't repeat because $x_i=x_j,\,i>j$ gets a contradiction regarding the tuth value of $Q(x_i,\,x_j)$. An infinite sequence with finitely many distinct elements repeats.

Comment: @J.G. I still do not get it, but thanks anyway for the help

Comment: **Hint:** Consider a finite model. For each element $x$ let $n(x)$ be the number of elements in the set $\{y:Q(x,y)\}$. Show that $Q(x,y)$ implies $n(x)\gt n(y)$.. Since the model is finite (and of course nonempty) there is an element $x$ where $n(x)$ attains its minimum value.

Comment: @bof What is $n(y)$?

Comment: $n(x)$ is the number of elements in the set $\{z:Q(x,z)\}$ and $n(y)$ is the number of elements in the set $\{z:Q(y,z)\}$.

Comment: @bof Okay, what's the consequence of $n(x)$ attaining its minimum value?

Comment: If $n(x)$ attains its minimum value at $x_1$, and if $Q(x_1,x_2)$, and if $n(x_1)\gt n(x_2)$, then we've got ourselves a contradiction, haven't we?